# Best way to pass state during initial load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application.

When a request hits the server for the first time I use the route and session to alter the initial state of my application on the server. I render the application in that state on the server and send back the html.

When those application assets hit the client, I need the dynamic state I created to be present so that the client doesn't render the app in it's default state, different from the state created on the server.

Right now I make another round trip to fetch the server's state before rendering client-side but I'd like to send that state with the initial load.

Is there a good way to do this other than jamming a script tag into the head with a global state variable.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong jamming a script tag into the head with a global state variable?  Actually, it will load slightly fast if you put the script tag at the end, and if you do a separate round trip instead, the HTML can be cached better.  I don't see any third way.

Comment: Why can't you show your default state? Maybe the default state should be something neutral you can send while fetching the correct data.

Comment: I can show default state, but I would rather show actual state immediately.